# When running `make installcheck` I get can not connect to database

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-extensions

On Ubuntu when I run `make installcheck` I'm getting

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin'    --inputdir=test --load-language=plpgsql --dbname=contrib_regression base math equality
(using postmaster on Unix socket, default port)
============== dropping database "contrib_regression" ==============
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
command failed: "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql" -X -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \"contrib_regression\"" "postgres"
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:272: recipe for target 'installcheck' failed
make: *** [installcheck] Error 2
```

What's the reason for this?

This is on the [`pg-bignum`](https://github.com/beargiles/pg-bignum) extension.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're trying to build an extension on Ubuntu, you may have to set the port to isolate which version of PostgreSQL you wish to test the extension on with `PGPORT`. You can see here `make install` check is connecting on `5433` with the socket name `.s.PGSQL.5432`,

You likely want port `5432`

```
make PGPORT=5433 installcheck
```